# Insert Data View greyed out with the Oslo master page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, oslo

I found [a very informative post about using SharePoint Designer with the Oslo master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87616/insert-menu-options-greyed-out-in-sharepoint-desinger-2013/), but its only advice was to switch to the Seattle page temporarily.  However, in doing so, I'm going to confuse a lot of my users who are accustomed to the Oslo look and feel; or, I'll have to do all my development work outside of business hours.

That post is over a year old.  Has there been a fix for the Oslo/SPD bug since then, or am I going to have change my master page and work after-hours?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the bug since I've never worked with oslo but maybe you can create a site page which inherits from seattle (to not disturb your users) and create a data view there. Then you can export the web part and import it in the oslo page using UI.